# How to convert a list of numbers to ctpyes array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, pointers, ctypes

I imported a C library into Python and want to use the C function from Python.

The data in Python is saved in a list, for example: `user_data = [1, 255, 30, 100, 0, 12, 5, 216]`. All elements in the list are numbers (0..255). I need to convert this number list to ctypes so that it can be input into the C function below.

The C function I will use is `int c_function(unsigned char* bytes)`; where the input argument is a pointer to an array of numbers. Note the input value is an array of numbers rather than an array of characters / a string, which means 0 is a normal number instead of a NUL termination character.

How can I convert a number list to a number array (more precisely, a pointer to a number array) in ctypes?

Comment: How does the C function know the length of the array?  Is it fixed?  show your code attempt, including a small C function example and the Python code to call it.  `bytes([1,255,30,100,0,12,5,216])` can be passed as the parameter, but the C function needs to know or assume the length.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the C function to be: int c_function(unsigned char *bytes, size_t len) as suggested by @Joseph. Actually, in my case, I know the length of the array in advance. The length is a fixed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `0` to just be a normal number, then you need another argument to your C function so that it knows how long the array is (unless the length is already known in advance on the C side). For the sake of a concrete example, I'll go with this as your C function:

```c
#include <stddef.h>

int c_function(unsigned char *bytes, size_t len) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += bytes[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Compile that with `gcc -fPIC -shared q72815146.c -o q72815146.so`, then do this in Python:

```py
from ctypes import *

mydll = CDLL("./q72815146.so")
mydll.c_function.restype = c_int
mydll.c_function.argtypes = (POINTER(c_ubyte), c_size_t)

def c_function(x):
    l = len(x)
    return mydll.c_function((c_ubyte * l)(*x), l)

user_data = [1,255,30,100,0,12,5,216]
print(c_function(user_data))
```

Comment: It really works! Thank you so much. I found that the commands:  `mydll.c_function.restype = c_int` AND `mydll.c_function.argtypes = (POINTER(c_ubyte), c_size_t)` are critical in Linux for the c_function to run. Otherwise, an error (**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**) will jump out. (But in Windows, these two commands looks not necessary. I have no idea why.) Thank you again. It helps me a lot~

Comment: @JING It's effectively just a coincidence that on Win32, the default types have the same representation as this function's actual types. You shouldn't rely on it and should keep those lines even on systems that appear to not need them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
import ctypes
user_data = [1, 255, 30, 100, 0, 12, 5, 216]
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(user_data))(*user_data)
```

this will convert the list into ctypes

Comment: Thank you. I tried it on both Windows and Linux. And I find it works on Windows but not Linux. I have no idea why. And @Joseph 's answer really works on Linux. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool!.If possible, can you tell me what error you got on linux?

Comment: Sure, the error is: **Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV**. And then I tried @Joseph 's answer. The error no longer occurs.